# curl --referer : no URL specified!

Tags: curl

Why I can't do curl `--referer` in my machine?

When I do `curl -i --referer https://google.com`

All I got is this:

> curl: no URL specified! curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

Comment: `--referer` takes an argument.  A referer is an URL, not a binary property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in [`man curl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl):

> *curl [options] [URL...]*

`--referer` is an option that takes an argument, and `https://google.com` is the argument for it.  You didn't provide any URL to fetch.

Answer (score -1):

you have not entered the url where the request will be sent

```
$ curl --referer <Referer_URL> <target_URL>
```

Example:

```
$ curl --referer http://google.com http://example.com
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that your answer seems to reiterate what was already stated in the accepted answer. You may want to consider expanding it so that the difference to that answer becomes more visible; otherwise it would be best paced as a comment to that answer (once you have sufficient reputation).